# Could the output of this MWE look nicer?

Tags: equations, amsmath

Figured out what was missing here, so it looks works fine. But it doesn't look fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
W_{chaste1}=\frac{1}{2}e^{\left[-Z_{\alpha}T_{3}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}A^{2}Q^{2}\left[\upsilon_{0}\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\upsilon_{1}\left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} + \upsilon_{2} \right]     
-Z_{\alpha}T_{2}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}A^{2}Q^{2}\left\{\upsilon_{0}\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\upsilon_{1}\left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} + \upsilon_{2} 
+Z_{\alpha}T_{3}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}Q^{2} + \upsilon_{0} \left[\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} + \upsilon_{1} \left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} + \upsilon_{2}
\right]\right\}\right]} 
\end{equation*}
```

Edit: @Marmot answered the question concerning the code and I have edited accordingly. However, can this be made to look better in latex

Comment: There is a backslash missing in the last `right\}`, which should be `\right\}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Remark: I updated the code and screenshot to make the solution correspond to the modified code posted by the OP.)

In addition to fixing the missing-backslash matter, you should (a) use a `multline*` environment and introduce two linebreaks and (b) employ inline-fraction notation. That way, the parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces don't have to be made overly large. Do observe that the newly-modified code uses exactly zero instances of `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*} 
W_{\textup{chaste1}}=\tfrac{1}{2} \exp\Bigl[
-Z^{}_{\alpha}T_{3}^{2/\alpha}A^{2}Q^{2} \bigl[
  \upsilon_{0}(L_{0}/L_{3})^{2/\alpha}
+ \upsilon_{1}(L_{1}/L_{3})^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \bigr] \\
-Z^{}_{\alpha} T_{2}^{2/\alpha}A^{2}Q^{2} \Bigl\{ 
  \upsilon_{0}(L_{1}/L_{2})^{2/\alpha}
+ \upsilon_{1}(L_{1}/L_{2})^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \\
+Z^{}_{\alpha} T_{3}^{2/\alpha}Q^{2} 
+ \upsilon_{0} \bigl[(L_{0}/L_{3})^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{1} (L_{1}/L_{3})^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \bigr]
\Bigr\} \Bigr]
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Depending on the meaning of the variables, an `align*` environment (with suitably chosen alignment points) may be preferable to the `multline*` environment employed above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\newcommand\Zalpha{Z^{\vphantom{/}}_{\alpha\vphantom{2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
W_{\textup{chaste1}}=\tfrac{1}{2} \exp\Bigl[
-&\Zalpha T_{3}^{\,2/\alpha} A^{2}Q^{2} \bigl[
  \upsilon_{0}(L_{0}/L_{3}{)}^{2/\alpha}
+ \upsilon_{1}(L_{1}/L_{3}{)}^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \bigr] \\
{}-{}&\Zalpha T_{2}^{\,2/\alpha} A^{2}Q^{2} \Bigl\{ 
  \upsilon_{0}(L_{1}/L_{2}{)}^{2/\alpha}
+ \upsilon_{1}(L_{1}/L_{2}{)}^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \\
{}+{}&\Zalpha T_{3}^{\,2/\alpha}Q^{2}
+ \upsilon_{0} \bigl[(L_{0}/L_{3}{)}^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{1} (L_{1}/L_{3}{)}^{2/\alpha} 
+ \upsilon_{2} \bigr]
\Bigr\} \Bigr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the answer based on the modified parameters in the question but It has to be peer-reviewed.

Comment: @Abdulhameed - Thanks. I've updated the code to make it correspond to the modified code in your query.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `e^` if the argument of the exponential is that long.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
W_\mathrm{chaste1}=\frac{1}{2}\exp&\left[-Z_{\alpha}T_{3}^{\frac{2}
{\alpha}}A^{2}Q^{2}\left\{\upsilon_{0}\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\upsilon_{1}\left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}
+ \upsilon_{2} \right\}\right.\\    
&{}~\left.
-Z_{\alpha}T_{2}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}A^{2}Q^{2}\left\{\upsilon_{0}\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}+\upsilon_{1}\left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}
+ \upsilon_{2}                    + Z_{\alpha}T_{3}^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}Q^{2} +
\upsilon_{0} \left[\left(\frac{L_{0}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} +
\upsilon_{1} \left(\frac{L_{1}}{L_{3}}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} +
\upsilon_{2}\right]\right\}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]